# Setting up Angular for production

Tags: angularjs, production

I have been trying to follow the suggestions for running an [angular app in production](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production). However I have been struggling to disable the comment and css class directives:

```
$compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled(false);
$compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled(false);
```

When I try to add these commands to the config block I receive the error:

```
$compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled is not a function
```

The codepen below demonstrates my issue, if you comment out the two lines then the code runs without any problem:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoaKbj?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two methods don't exist in the [1.5.8 version](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider) of angular that you're using.

They exist in the [1.6.0-rc.0 version](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0-rc.0/docs/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider) though.

Comment: Strange, I wonder why they removed it from 1.5.8? I can't load 1.6.0-rc.0  with npm dependencies so I guess I will have to it load externally.

Comment: They only added it in 1.6. It didn't exist before.